# How to retrieve data after any string match in MySql?

Tags: mysql

I wish to retrieve data after any string match in a given data.

For example I have data string as: "K Anil Babu"

I have data in table register_table with column authors which matches the given string as:
Anil, Anil Babu, anil, Anil B, anil babu.

I have used query as:

```
 select authors from register_table WHERE authors like '%K Anil Babu%';
```

No data displays when I execute this query. 
How to match and display any string with the given string

Comment: your query is looking for strings that contains K Anil Babu. You need to explode that string in single words and then do the like on each

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT authors 
FROM register_table 
WHERE LOCATE(authors, "K Anil Babu");
```

Result

```
+-----------+
|  authors  |
+-----------+
| Anil      |
| Anil Babu |
| anil      |
| Anil B    |
| anil babu |
+-----------+
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e9ff92d64f0fefda039d451d8e903f79

---

Table Structure & sample data

```
CREATE TABLE register_table(
    authors_id int,
    authors varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO register_table
VALUES  
(1, 'Sunil'),
(2, 'Anil'),
(3, 'Anil Babu'),
(4, 'anil'),
(5, 'Anil B'),
(6, 'anil babu'),
(7, 'Patsy W. Duncan'),
(8, 'Jeffery E.'),
(9, 'Herbst'),
(10, 'Andrew C. Mack');
```

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/func_mysql_locate.asp